# SSMS (MS SQL Server Management Studio) save job into comma delimited csv

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am really new in MS SQL Server Management. 
I create job.. Then I choose advanced in job steps..and choose to save as test.csv.

```
SELECT  
T0.U_Scid as 'id',
T3.U_Boarding as 'start',
...
T3.U_Boarding as 'end', 
T2.Name as 'service_classification',
T5.U_Type as 'equipment'

FROM  [XXX].[dbo].[@COR_SC_EQUIP] T5,[XXX].[dbo].[@COR_SC_GENERAL] T3, 
      [XXX].[dbo].[@COR_SC_HEADER] T0

INNER JOIN [XXX].[dbo].[OSCS] T1 on T0.U_Status = T1.statusID
INNER JOIN [XXX].[dbo].[OSCO] T2 on T0.U_Classifi = T2.originID
WHERE T3.U_ScID = T0.U_ScID AND T5.U_ScID = T0.U_SciD AND T3.U_Boarding > 
'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' 

ORDER BY T3.U_ScID
```

And when I open test.csv, I have data in this format: 217775
 2016-07-21 00:00:00.000 (...between is huge gap...) 2016-07-21 (...between is huge gap...) 00:00:00.000  (....between is huge gap...)               66 ...   and not comma delimited.

Should I change type  from Transact-SQL into something else? So when I want to import it into database it will be in right format.

When I run sql I am able to copy table with header and save it into EXCEL and import it easily into another database. But I would like to do it auutomatically every day. 
I already set..but the format is not suitable for importing into another database

Thank you so much for your advice

Comment: I think you should take a look at SSIS (Integration Services). There are many examples on the web on how to export a query to csv and then run the SSIS package from a job. http://bpmdeveloper.com/ssis-package-export-data-to-csv-file/

Comment: thank you..I will have a look

Comment: You're welcome. You should start by downloading Visual Studio 2015 (community edition is free)

Comment: It look likes you are saving with the extension of .csv, but you may have chosen tab delimited rather than comma delimited as the export type.  That would explain the "gaps" as it does this with tab delimited files.  However, as the others recommended, creating an SSIS package via SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015 would be a much more robust solution if you plan on doing these types of exports in the future as you can setup package to also transfer the file automatically between servers.

Comment: I am curious about transfering between servers too..Can I make csv output and transfer to other server in one SSIS package?

Comment: I go step by step from tutorial and when I saw preview of the file .. I got values from 3 column into my first column.

Comment: Everything is working now. THANK YOU ;)

Comment: @Burco Great. For between servers you don't need a csv at all if SSIS can connect to both servers. Look for more tutorials online. SSIS is a great tool for ETL.

Comment: On one server I have MS SQL server management..which is having data from SAP ..on other server I have web aplication.So I want to export some data from query..transfer it into another server. And on that second server import it into database. I would like to do it automatically..On SSMS side through SSIS ..on other cron script which is going import csv. Or can SSIS do this also?

Comment: @Burco Usually you schedule SSIS packages from SqlServer jobs. I didn't get your full picture, sorry, but on transferring data you can do almost anything with SSIS.